# Excel: Max value in row that is determined by a lookup

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to create a column that will lookup the text in column A, find the row of this text in another sheet table which is referenced by a name range in row 2, and then find the maximum number in that row on the referenced sheet. Below is the closest I've gotten (which I know isn't good). The formula has gotten more complicated as I've tried more possible ways of making this work. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
=max(indirect(address(row(VLOOKUP(A9,INDIRECT(W$2),MATCH('Main Tab'!$R9,dates,1),FALSE)),2)&":"&(address(row(VLOOKUP($G9&": "&$A9,INDIRECT(W$2),MATCH('Main Tab'!$R9,dates,1),FALSE)),10000))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get there with a method like yours, but there is a simpler way using array formulas.

Sample data (`A1:H6`):

```
lion      53    52    40    75    27    25    99
tiger     87    63    75    8     76    82    32
cat       56    63    26    23    84    12    100
dog       66    33    91    17    16    85    1
rabbit    66    64    87    80    20    41    37
bird      56    93    61    19    58    94    73
```

In `J1`: `dog`
In `K1`: `{=MAX(IF($A$1:$A$6=$J1, $B$1:$H$6))}` (array formula; confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>)

An explanation to help understand the logic:

- `IF(A1:A6=J1, ...)` tests whether the value in the first column is equal to the value in `J1`.

  - If yes, it returns the value in the same row of `B1:H6`.
  - If no, it returns false.
- `MAX()` then takes the maximum of the transformed `B1:H6`.

*E.g.*, when `J1`=`dog`, `A1:H6` would look like this:

```
FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
TRUE     66       33       91       17       16       85       1
FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
```